# how to fit content of reports so that we can print it on A4 size

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have created a report in ssrs 2008 r2.It is larger then the normal A4 size .So when i export the report in word i see it clearly but when i see print preview of the report in to the word its contents get cut from the right end.I think it is due to report size. Is there any way so that we can fit the content at the time of export in to the ms word so that user can clearly take a print out in A4 size.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear to me; particularly your last sentence is hard to understand. Could you edit your question, and add some clarification? In addition, it would help if you add to your question what you've tried to solve this, and why it didn't work.

Comment: i am trying to say that my reports body size is 12.4 -> width and 10.1 -> height . when i export report as word in doc format and open it and change page size to A4 The report get cut form the right side.

my points are low so i cant attache images but thanks for you response

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to do this is to physically decrease the size of your report when building it as there is no auto size capability in report builder.

1. Right click and properties on the grey back ground. Then change the size and orientation as required.
2. Then click on the white body and ensure the properties bar is open. Expand the size properties option and set the size of your report to reflect the previous selection.
3. Also don't forget to set the margins as this will effect the amount of printable space on your report.
4. Lastly ensure you alter the size of you fonts and report parts to fit on the size required.

I'd love to see an automatic sizing feature in the report builder for exporting.

Comment: Is this still true for later versions of SSRS/SSDT?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your report content size is greater than the report size.
Report size for an A4 page is 8.5*11 inch,if your content is greater than the report size then it will move the columns to the next .

Adjust the Size of each Tablix which should be less than your report size.

Select Tablix to view properties.
expand the size option and adjust width and height accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just increase height and width of paper size in Report builder properties. Doesn't have any sense but it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

In Report Builder in the Report Properties change the width of the report so that it exceeds the width of your data. Exporting to both Word and PDF will mean that it fits the page width. You can also adjust the height so that the report fills your desired paper size.