# Page margins in SSRS report overflowing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, margins, page-size

I have report containing 6 subreports and when I preview it shows blank pages and tablix gets overflown to next page as below.

[image: Tablix preview]

Report properties shows as below:

[image: Report Properties]

I am checking the sub-reports and unable to progress.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page margins in SSRS report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721913/page-margins-in-ssrs-report)

Comment: Any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: Yes, delete your duplicate question.

Comment: how to resolve issue with page margins?

Answer (score 3):

Your body size plus margins (x 2) size are greater than the width of your paper.

You also need to check your page size.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890309/how-to-fit-content-of-reports-so-that-we-can-print-it-on-a4-size) explains in more detail.

For future reference I suggest you create two page templates (Landscape and Portrait) which are just blank reports ready to copy and paste into new projects then the issue won't re-occur!

Bear in mind that (annoyingly) the page width automatically expands if you add controls to your report which can't fit on the page.

Comment: I just exported my report to word and it shows in 4 pages. I selected the Report Body properties and Width shows as 1pt. Any idea what this must be set to?

Comment: Within report designer you need to add up your dimensions in mm and then compare with your page size (A4?).